# Como pegar qualquer tipo de cookie utilizando o Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, criptografia, cookies, selenium-webdriver

## Resumo

*Para resumir tudo que eu falei aqui embaixo, eu preciso abrir o Whatsapp Web ler o QR Code e salvar os cookies para que na próxima inicialização do Selenium eu não precise ler o QR Code novamente.

    Eu encontrei uma solução utilizando profile, a ideia é boa, mas preciso de algo escalável, e os cookies seriam a melhor opção.*

### O início da grande jornada

Eu consigo pegar alguns *cookies* em uma determinada página, mas em outra não, existe "tipo" de *cookie* diferente?

Estou utilizando o seguinte código para salvar os *cookies*:

```
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver 

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

E este outro para carregar os *cookies*:

```
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver 

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Fonte: [How to save and load cookies using python selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver).

Da forma que esta funciona perfeitamente com o Google, mas o que eu preciso é pegar os *cookies* do Whatsapp Web. A princípio pensei que poderia ser por causa do tempo, já que os *cookies* são criados somente depois que o *QR Code* é lido, mas coloquei um *time* de 20 segundos, tempo suficiente para leitura, mas mesmo assim não funcionou:

```
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver
import time

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
time.sleep(20)
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))
```

E os *cookies* são criados, já verifiquei no navegador:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não estou entendendo porque que ele consegue pegar no Google e no Whatsapp Web não. Existe algum tipo de *cookie* protegido ou diferente? Se tem como posso pega-lo? O que eu estou precisando é iniciar o Firefox com o *QR Code* já lido, a ideia é pegar o *cookie* na primeira inicialização e nas outras "exporta" este *cookie* para não precisar ler de novo já que o Selenium inicializa um navegador limpo.

### Update 1 - A esperança no JavaScript

Fiz um novo teste utilizando um *script* JavaScript.

Utilizei o seguinte *script*:

```
var getCookies = function(){
  var pairs = document.cookie.split(";");
  var cookies = {};
  for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++){
    var pair = pairs[i].split("=");
    cookies[pair[0]] = unescape(pair[1]);
  }
  return cookies;
}

return getCookies();
```

Obs: Este 'return' é para o Selenium conseguir pegar o retorno do *script*.

Fonte: [I need to get all the cookies from the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252665/i-need-to-get-all-the-cookies-from-the-browser)

Assim eu faço o Selenium executar este *script* e pegar o resultado:

```
import selenium.webdriver
import os
from pprint import pprint
import time

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
#driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

time.sleep(20)
print 'Pegando os cookies'

script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
script = open(os.path.join(script_path, "js_scripts/get_all_cookies.js"), "r").read()
cookies = driver.execute_script(script)
pprint(cookies)

print 'Pegou!'
```

Utilizando o Whatsapp o resultado é (cmd):

```
Pegando os cookies
{u'': u'undefined'}
Pegou!
```

E quando eu utilizo o Google o resultado é (cmd):

```
Pegando os cookies
{u'1P_JAR': u'2017-11-21-12'}
Pegou!
```

Será que há algum tipo de bloqueio, ou algum tipo de *cookie* diferente como falei anteriormente? Eu consigo ver o conteúdo dele nas configurações do Firefox:

Cookie 1:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cookie 2:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível pegar estes cookies de alguma forma, ou guardar esta sessão para não precisar fazer a leitura do *QR Code* novamente?

### Update 2 - Profile, uma solução não escalável

Cheguei perto de uma solução, não sei se isso vai ajudar, mas de qualquer forma vou postar:

```
import selenium.webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import FirefoxProfile
profile = FirefoxProfile('C:\Users\meu_usuario\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\oedq4f8r.default')
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
```

O que este código faz, ele pega o *profile default* e abre o Firefox com ele, então se eu ler o *QR Code* antes, e mando o Selenium abrir funciona, mas se eu ler o *QR Code* com o Selenium e abro de novo não funciona, ou seja de alguma forma o Selenium não consegue salvar os *cookies* no *profile*/sessão.

### Update 3 - Os cookies estão protegidos?

Estava verificando os *cookies*, reparei que os que eu consigo pegar tem a seguinte descrição em "enviar" "Qualquer tipo de conexão", enquanto os que eu não consigo pegar esta assim "Só conexões criptografadas".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Update 4 - Será que é possível acessar estes cookies?

> Instrui o navegador para nunca enviar o *cookie* sob uma requisição HTTP
>   sem que esta esteja em um canal de comunicação cifrado. O *cookie* só
>   pode ser enviado através de HTTPS. Isso funciona mesmo se o usuário
>   digitar manualmente um pedido de HTTP. A solicitação HTTP será
>   enviada, mas o navegador não enviará quaisquer *cookies* marcados como
>   "seguro". Esta medida visa minimizar o cenário no qual um usuário
>   malicioso induz a vítima a realizar uma requisição HTTP, o que poderá
>   permitir a captura do *cookie* de sessão da vítima. Tal captura pode ser
>   feita através de ferramentas que analisam o tráfego de rede, como
>   *sniffers* ou através do *log* de acesso da aplicação.

Ou seja se eu estive utilizando uma comunicação http eu não vou conseguir pegar estes *cookies*, não sei como funciona o acesso do *drive* do Selenium, a princípio achei que era realmente como um *drive* de *hardware*, servido apenas como uma ponte, mas quando eu fui utilizar o *drive* para o Chrome ele parecia um endereço local HTTP com uma porta, será que existe alguma forma de acessar utilizando HTTPS? Seria diferente a comunicação do Google Chrome e do Firefox, pois ao rodar o *drive* do Firefox esta informação não aparece.

### Update 5 - Como funciona esta proteção?

Fiz mais alguns teste, pensei, vou criar um *cookie secure*, assim vou ter a certeza que é isso, mas ai me vem a surpresa, ele consegue pegar o *cookie secure* que eu criei, mas não consegue pegar qualquer *cookie* com o valor encriptado (pelo menos eu acho que esta encriptado, vou mostrar aqui as imagens).

Executei o seguinte código no Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import selenium.webdriver
from pprint import pprint
import os


def prepara_script(nome_script):
    try:
        script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    except NameError:
        script_path = os.getcwd()
    return open(os.path.join(script_path, nome_script + ".js"), "r").read()

os.system('cls')
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
script = prepara_script("get_cookies")
Store = driver.execute_script(script)
pprint(Store)
```

O JavaScript usado foi este:

```
var getCookies = function(){
  var pairs = document.cookie.split(";");
  var cookies = {};
  for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++){
    var pair = pairs[i].split("=");
    cookies[pair[0]] = unescape(pair[1]);
  }
  return cookies;
}
document.cookie = "tagname = test;secure";
var cookies = getCookies();
console.log(cookies);
console.log(document.cookie);
```

Resultado no *console*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cookies do navegador:

*Cookie* 1
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Cookie* 2
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Cookie* 3
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Cookie* 4
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como vocês podem ver, todos os *cookies* com o valor encriptado eu não consigo pegar, fiz este teste utilizando o Google, já que para fazer testes utilizando o Whatsapp Web eu tenho que ler em todo momento o QR Code.

### Update 6 - O retorno do Update 4

"Será que é possível acessar estes *cookies*?"

> Também existem os *supercookies* extremamente invasivos. A operadora
>   americana Verizon é uma das companhias que está apoiando esse tipo de
>   rastreamento. Esses cookies são inseridos ao nível do ISP (Provedor de
>   Serviço Internet), então eles não ficam na sua máquina, mas
>   identificam os sites que você visita. Por eles estarem no nível ISP e
>   não no nível PC é impossível erradicá-los rapidamente apagando o seu
>   histórico. Depois de uma checada do FCC (órgão regulamentar dos EUA,
>   equivalente à Anatel) ano passado, os *supercookies* da Verizon agora
>   são opcionais e mais fáceis de configurar pelos usuários.

Eu consigo pelo menos saber se estes *cookies* que estou tentando pegar é um "*supercookie*"?

Fonte: http://gizmodo.uol.com.br/guia-completo-cookies-navegadores/

Comment: Parabéns pelo detalhe de sua pergunta. De acordo com meus testes, os cookies tok e ref ficam armazenados no path /pp e o selenium.get_cookies(), por alguma razão, não retorna cookies em paths diferentes de /. Se na janela aberta você editar os cookies gerados pelo web.whatsapp.com para que o path seja /, o get_cookies retorna esses cookies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso é um cookie [HTTP(S) Only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie), ou seja, ele não pode ser acessado via javascript.

Para pegar ele, você pode acessar os cabeçalhos HTTP da requisição. Eu uso para isso a lib em python seleninum-requests, que é parecida com a lib requests do Python.

```
from seleniumrequests import Firefox
webdriver = Firefox()

response = webdriver.request('GET', 'https://www.google.com/')
print (response.cookies)
```

Mas testando no web.whatsapp.com, realmente não pega nenhum cookie, porque o web.whatsapp.com não envia nenhum cookie, pelo menos não via HTTP. O que significa que ele só pode estar setando isso no Javascript.

Dando uma olhada nos códigos javascript procurando por `Cookie`, descobri um dos métodos de uma classe javascript chamado `setRefTokCookies`. O método está minificado, mas eu dei uma formatada nele e ele ficou assim:

```
setRefTokCookies:function(e, p){
    d.setCookie({
        name:g.COOKIE_REF,
        value:e,
        path:g.PP_REF,
        domain:g.COOKIE_DOMAIN,
        secure:!0
    });

    var n={
        name:g.COOKIE_TOK,
        value:p,
        path:g.PP_TOK,
        domain:g.COOKIE_DOMAIN,
        secure:!0
    };
    d.setCookie(n)
}
```

Opa, agora ficou interessante. Esse método seta 2 cookies, sendo o nome de um vindo da constante `COOKIE_REF` e o outro vindo da constante `COOKIE_TOK`. Bem parecidas com os nomes dos cookies armazenados, né?

Agora temos que descobrir quem é o valor `p` e `e` passados pra esse método. O problema é que, como o código está minificado, não é trivial entender ele.

Olhando com calma esse código, para ver se descobria o nome da classe desse método, eu percebi que ele sempre fazia um teste antes de continuar chamando o restante do código. Esse teste é:

```
if (!Store.Conn.me)
    return r.error("userPrefs: Me has not loaded yet.")
```

Bacana. Temos um cara agora chamado `Store`, global, que parece ter dados interessantes e é usado pela nossa classe de interesse. Abrindo o Developer Toolbar na pagina do https://web.whatsapp.com e analisando o conteúdo do objeto `Store.Conn`, temos uma agradável surpresa. 2 variáveis contem o conteúdo exato desses 2 tokens, são elas `Store.Conn.__x_ref` e `Store.Conn.__x_serverToken`. Sabendo isso, fazer o código que pega essas informações fica trivial:

```
import selenium.webdriver

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")

driver.execute_script('console.log(Store.Conn.__x_ref);')
driver.execute_script('console.log(Store.Conn.__x_serverToken)')
```

Depois de passado o QR Code, ele traz os valores iguais aos dos cookies.

ps: Existem outros dados interessantes de autenticação nessa `Store.Conn`, talvez o mais interessante seja salvar ele inteiro e depois apenas reatributir o conteúdo na `Store.Conn`, já que essa variável é global.

Comment: Funcionou para pegar a informação, mas não conseguir setar para deixar logado, já que esta acabando o tempo da recompensa vou atribuir a você, já que foi genial a sua resposta, obrigado pelo esforço em me ajudar

Comment: ótima resposta! especialmente pelas dicas de executar javascript no selenium :-)