# Trabalhando com Cookie em PHP

Tags: php

Tenho esse código de onde pego dados de um formulário e envio para uma outra pagina através da `section`.

```
session_start();

$login = $_GET['login'];
echo("$login");

$obj1->nome = $_GET['first_name'];
$obj1->codigo = $_GET['security_phrase'];
$obj1->numeroEmAtendimento = $_GET['phone_number'];
$obj1->numero2 = $_GET['tel2'];
$obj1->numero3 = $_GET['tel3'];
$obj1->numero4 = $_GET['tel4'];
$obj1->numero5 = $_GET['tel5'];
$obj1->numero6 = $_GET['tel6'];
$obj1->nascimento = $_GET['nascimento'];
$obj1->sexo = $_GET['sexo'];
$obj1->endereco = $_GET['endereco'];
$obj1->numero = $_GET['numero_endereco'];
$obj1->bairro = $_GET['bairro'];
$obj1->cidade = $_GET['cidade'];
$obj1->uf = $_GET['estado'];
$obj1->cep = $_GET['cep'];
$obj1->agencia = $_GET['agencia'];
$obj1->conta = $_GET['conta'];

$getDadosPropectEmAtendimento = json_encode($obj1);

echo "Dados enviados com sucesso...";

$nome = "testecookie";
$valor = "$getDadosPropectEmAtendimento";
$expira = time() + 3600;
setcookie($nome, $valor, $expira);

$ler = $_COOKIE['testecookie'];
echo "Valor do Cookie masterdaweb: $ler";

$_SESSION['getDadosPropectEmAtendimento'] = $getDadosPropectEmAtendimento;
```

No outro arquivo tenho esses código:

```
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['getDadosPropectEmAtendimento'];

$ler = $_COOKIE['testecookie'];

echo "Valor do Cookie masterdaweb: $ler";
```

O código está executando da forma que preciso, porém no meu navegador.

A minha pergunta é: tem algo que eu possa fazer para um outro sistema acessar essas informações que passei para a `section` deste segundo arquivo através do Cookie?

Comment: Se não me engano, cookies só podem ser acessados pelo domínio que o criou.  Leia [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257023/como-pegar-qualquer-tipo-de-cookie-utilizando-o-selenium), apesar de não ser exatamente o que vc quer, ela é bem detalhada, vai te esclarecer algumas coisas

Comment: Poderia definir "outro sistema", por favor? Aliás, esse "section" seria a sessão?

Comment: é um sistema de integração com outro sistema esse sistema precisa acessar essas informações para importar eles entendeu?

Comment: o que quer dizer com outro sistema?

Comment: Então não use sessão para isso. Faça a integração de uma forma decente e envie via requisição HTTP os dados. Ou persista em um banco de dados compartilhado. Dependerá muito de como é o ambiente, do que exatamente são esses "sistemas", como estão estruturados, etc. Mas, com certeza, sessão e cookie não serão a solução.

Comment: Perfeito vou procurar como trabalhar com requisições HTTP para ver se facilita minha vida pois estou com problemas e preciso resolver isso hj